# How to detect a click on the checkbox within a ListView when the its focusable is set to false

Tags: java, android-studio

I am working on an application where I need to create a list. The list contains 2 textViews and 1 checkbox. The list has to delete the row which detects a click on it. But the click will only be detected when the checkbox's focusability is set to false. But the aim of the application is to also delete the row when the respective checkbox is checked.
But the onItemClickListener does not detect the click on the checkbox.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
ArrayList<ListData> ListData = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting");
    final ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter(this ,R.layout.list_layout,ListData );
    Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    CheckBox checkBox =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
            EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
            if (editText1.getText() != null && editText2!=null) {
                String title = editText1.getText().toString();
                String description = editText2.getText().toString();
                textView1.setText(title);
                textView2.setText(description);
                ListData data = new ListData(title, description);
                ListData.add(data);
                saveArrayList();
                Log.i(TAG, "display:" + ListData);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editText1.setText("");
                editText2.setText("");
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }


        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: tapped");
            ListData.remove(i);
            saveArrayList();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

The XML file is

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="90"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusedByDefault="false" />
```